# Editing/Listing multiple models within one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, viewmodel

I am new to the MVC and EF world. I am targeting MVC 4 EF 5 using code first.

I am looking for the best practice for editing two related models using one view. For simplicity I have the following two Models:

```
namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class Contact
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
     }
}
```

and

```
namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class PhoneNumber
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public bool Primary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

with the following context:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace AddressBook.Models
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The relationship between the Contact and PhoneNumber is one to many, However I would like to be able to edit the first_name, last_name and Number when the Primary is set to true, so we would be editing only one phone number per contact record.

I have seen similar posts that point to using a ViewModel but the only examples of viewmodels I have seen are when used instead of the viewbag when passing the information for a dropdown.

I guess I have a few questions:

1. would the ViewModel look like below?

   ```
   public class ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel
   {
       public Contact ContactToEdit {get; set;}
       public PhoneNumber PhoneNumberToEdit {get;set;}
   }
   ```
2. what would the edit(post) and edit(get) look like?

Any help would be appreciated to help me wrap my head around this ...

here is the Edit(get) modified to support if contact does not have phone number associated

' // GET: /Contact/Edit/5

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber = (from pn in db.PhoneNumbers
                                                              where pn.ContactID == id && pn.Primary == true
                                                              select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel { ContactID = pn.ContactID, First_Name = pn.Contact.First_Name, Last_Name = pn.Contact.Last_Name, Number = pn.Number }).SingleOrDefault();



        if (ContactPrimaryNumber == null)
        {
            ContactPrimaryNumber = (from c in db.Contacts
                                                                  where c.ID == id
                                                                  select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel { ContactID = c.ID, First_Name = c.First_Name, Last_Name = c.Last_Name, Number = null }).Single();

        }
        return View(ContactPrimaryNumber);
    }'
```

so the final solution after everyones help is:

the models:

```
    public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

}

    public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }


}
```

The controler edit(get and post)

```
        // GET: /Contact/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {

        ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber = (from c in db.Contacts
                                                              join pn in db.PhoneNumbers
                                                              on c.ID equals pn.ContactID into outer
                                                              from _pn in outer.Where(p => p.Primary ==true).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                              where c.ID == id 
                                                              select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel { ContactID = c.ID, First_Name = c.First_Name, Last_Name = c.Last_Name, Number = ((_pn == null) ? "" : _pn.Number) }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (ContactPrimaryNumber == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(ContactPrimaryNumber);
    }

    // POST: /Contact/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber)
    {
        Contact c = db.Contacts.Find(ContactPrimaryNumber.ContactID);
        PhoneNumber pn = db.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == ContactPrimaryNumber.ContactID && x.Primary == true);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            c.First_Name = ContactPrimaryNumber.First_Name;
            c.Last_Name = ContactPrimaryNumber.Last_Name;

            if (pn == null) //if there is no phone number associated with the contact in the DB
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactPrimaryNumber.Number))
                {
                    //Add a new phonenumber in the database

                    PhoneNumber Px = new PhoneNumber();

                    Px.ContactID = ContactPrimaryNumber.ContactID;
                    Px.Number = ContactPrimaryNumber.Number;
                    Px.Primary = true;

                    db.PhoneNumbers.Add(Px);

                }

            }
            else //if there is a phone number associated with the contactin the DB
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactPrimaryNumber.Number))
                {
                    //delete the existing number
                    db.PhoneNumbers.Remove(pn);

                }
                else
                {
                    //modify the existing number
                    pn.Number = ContactPrimaryNumber.Number;
                }
            }


            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(c);
    }
```

and the viewmodel

```
    public class ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel
{

    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }


}
```

thanks again for your help

Comment: First you need a Contact foreign key in PhoneNumber, then you can have a custom save method. I will write it up in a few

Comment: Hi Komenge ... thanks for the reply ... I just noticed the foreign key also when I tried to generate the scafolding and it didnt create the viewbag for me automaticaly looks like this now 'public class PhoneNumber
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public bool Primary { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ContactID { get; set; }
        public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    }'

Comment: Mhmm One more question before i write you my answer, why does contact need to have multiple numbers? Is it really necessary?

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: this is a simplified version of the problem I am trying to understand how to use multiple models in one view. I am trying to avoid the user to have to do multiple posts to add/modify a Contact then seperately add/modify the primary number of the contact. I understand that the relationship between the models is one to many and I want it to act as if it is 1 to 1 for this screen. But the Contact can have more than one number associated just only one primary.

Comment: The solution is much simpler on one-to-one, with one-to-many it would be impossible to define a finite amount of number objects a contact may have. This can only be possible in separate views after Contact has already been created. If you need an answer for one-to-one i may be able to assist.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: but the contact will only have one phone number with Primary = true ... so on create it will default the primary to true and for edit it will only edit the primary phone number

Comment: `public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }` makes Contact collect a list of PhoneNumbers. Change it to `public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber {get;set;}` to limit it to only one PhoneNumber per Contact

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: I think if I can figure out how to write the linq to be something like 'from x in db.Contacts
                                                                      .Include(o => o.PhoneNumbers)   
                                                                      .Where(o => o.ID == id )
                                                                      .Where(o=> o.PhoneNumbers.primary == true'     its just that its not letting me have a where clause with the child table

Comment: @KomengeMwandila: but if I do that I wont be able to add multiple phone numbers to contacts when adding phone numbers and associating them to a contact using the vanilla scafolding screens. Like I said the relationship for buissness purposes needs to be 1 to many not one to one

Comment: Gotcha, give a few minutes i will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your view model should look like this:

```
public class ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And your update would look something like:

```
Contact c = context.Contacts.Find(id);
PhoneNumber p = context.PhoneNumbers
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id && x.Primary == true);
//validate input
//update as necessary
//SaveChanges() etc...
```

---

from your comment - you new up the model class `ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel`:

```
var ContactPrimaryNumber = 
    from pn in db.PhoneNumbers 
    where pn.ContactID == id && pn.Primary == true 
    select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel() {
        ContactID = pn.ContactID, 
        First_Name = pn.Contact.First_Name, 
        Last_Name = pn.Contact.Last_Name, 
        Number = pn.Number
    };
```

Comment: Hi qujck ... thanks for your reply ... I think by update your specifying the edit[HttpPost] what would the edit(get) look like isnt that where I have to associate my models to the viewmodel

Comment: it's a standard projection query newing up an instance of ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel

Comment: thats the path I started go on last night this is what I am using 'var ContactPrimaryNumber = from pn in db.PhoneNumbers where pn.ContactID == id && pn.Primary == true select new { ContactID = pn.ContactID, First_Name = pn.Contact.First_Name, Last_Name = pn.Contact.Last_Name, Number = pn.Number };' but I am getting an error : **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'** I think I understand the error that I am trying to assign an annonymous type thats been created by the projection to my veiwmodel type. However I dont know what to do to fix it.

Comment: I changed it to 'ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber = (from pn in db.PhoneNumbers
                                                                 where pn.ContactID == id && pn.Primary == true
select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel{ ContactID = pn.ContactID, First_Name = pn.Contact.First_Name, Last_Name = pn.Contact.Last_Name, Number = pn.Number }).Single();
' so now the Edit(get) is working the way I want it to. moving on to the edit(post) will follow your guidlines and keep you updated. I think your sending me on the right track

Comment: As far as validating input on Edit(post) I cant use if(ModelState.IsValid) how do I validate for each model I am using the following to set my models from the viewmodel passed in as follows: ' Contact c = db.Contacts.Find(ContactPrimaryNumber.ContactID);
            PhoneNumber pn = db.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == ContactPrimaryNumber.ContactID && x.Primary == true);
'

Comment: use DataAnnotations: check this link http://www.howmvcworks.net/OnModelsAndViewModels/UsingDataAnnotationsForValidation and google

Comment: aha ... now I see why everyone says to use a viewmodel for your views vs the entitymodel I have used the annotations on the entity model up to now and when you first said to use dataannotations on the viewmodel I was thinking to myself that I would be duplicating the logic on the viewmodel but I think the attributes should just be in one place the viewmodel. I am trying it out now

Comment: when editing a contact that doesnt have a phone number associated yet get an error on the edit(get) on this line 'ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber = (from pn in db.PhoneNumbers where pn.ContactID == id && pn.Primary == true
select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel{ ContactID = pn.ContactID, First_Name = pn.Contact.First_Name, Last_Name=pn.Contact.Last_Name, Number = pn.Number }).SingleOrDefault();' I was getting the eror when using .Single() but also getting it with .SingleORDefault(). I have to edit a record even if it doesnt have a number associated with it

Comment: well the ContactPrimaryNumber is set to null thats the issue(the error is the reult of it being null down the chain). FirstOrDefault or SingleOrDefault return null when there are no records. would I have to do another linq query if the ContactPrimaryNumber is null to just query the contact table with a empty place holder for Number

Comment: You need to do an `outer join` to select the Contact and optionally the primary number

Comment: :exactly thats what I would do if I were doing it with ado/sql but how do I do that in EF I am trying to use linq to entity syntax

Comment: I just edited my question to contain the edit(get) this seems to work for retrieving a contact that doesnt have a phone associated. but would rather do it cleaner with an outer join as you stated above if possible

Comment: Is Contact - PhoneNumber a 2 way association? I.e. can you do Contact.PhoneNumbers?

Comment: not sure what you mean the relationship in a database would be 1 contact to many phonenumbers but can only have one primary phone number

Comment: the outer join syntax I have is: 'ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber = (from c in db.Contacts join pn in db.PhoneNumbers on c.ID equals pn.ContactID into outer from pn in outer.DefaultIfEmpty() where c.ID == id where pn.Primary == true select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel { ContactID = c.ID, First_Name = c.First_Name, Last_Name = c.Last_Name, Number = ((pn == null) ? "(no numbers)" : pn.Number) }).SingleOrDefault();
' but it is still returning a null am I doing my outer join correctly

Comment: ok got the outer join to work ... it was the where clause thats funky 'ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel ContactPrimaryNumber = (from c in db.Contacts join pn in db.PhoneNumbers on c.ID equals pn.ContactID into outer from _pn in outer.Where(p => p.Primary ==true).DefaultIfEmpty() where c.ID == id select new ContactPrimaryNumberViewModel { ContactID = c.ID, First_Name = c.First_Name, Last_Name = c.Last_Name, Number = ((_pn == null) ? "(no numbers)" : _pn.Number) }).FirstOrDefault();
' ... getting closer

Comment: ok I got it to work n to n ... thank you so much for your help I will post the whole solution in case some one else needs to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this:

**PhoneNumber**

```
public class PhoneNumber
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public bool Primary { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contact"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int? ContactId { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
```

**Contact**

```
public class Contact
{  
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

**SaveContact**: depending on how you have set up your Repositories or Ef class. This can either go in your EfRepository implemention or your EfDb class.

```
public void SavePlayer(Contact contact)
    {
        using (var context = new EfDb())
        {                
            if (contact.ContactId == 0)
            {                    
                context.Contacts.Add(contact);
            }
            else if (contact.ContactId > 0)
            {
                var currentContact = context.Contacts
                    .Include(c => c.PhoneNumber)
                    .Single(c => c.ContactId== contact.ContactId);

                context.Entry(currentContact).CurrentValues.SetValues(contact);
                currentContact.PhoneNumber= contact.PhoneNumber;
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Edit action**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var contact= _dataSource.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        return View(player);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Contact contact)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _dataSource.SaveContact(contact);
                return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
        }            
        return View(contact);
    }
```

**Views**

In your `Contact View Folder` add `EditorTemplates folder`. Then Scaffold a `Create Strongly Typed PhoneNumber Partial View to this folder` and name it `PhoneNumber` like its model.

Scaffold a `Create Strongly Typed Contact View` name it `Create`

Then add `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)` to the master Create View.

Comment: @KomengeMwadila: Thanks ... I am trying it now

Comment: @KomengeMwadila: I have followed you up to creating the partial view in the newly created EditorTemplates folder. lost me at "Contact View name it Create" where do I add this view to is this not the same as the Create/edit/... I already have from the scafolding generation

Comment: @KomengeMwadila: when I add @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber) to the Create View for Contact it rightfully states that the PhoneNumber is not part of the model passed to it

Comment: @user2129585 The `Contact view` would be the master page, so it will automatically be called `Create`. All depends what Model you are passing to the Contact View.

Comment: @KomengeMwadila: we are passing the contacts Model in your edit(get) code above.

Comment: @KomengeMwadila: I guess I am confused as in our Contact edit(get) we pass the contacts model but then in the contact create view your saying to use this code '@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)' which is assuming our model has a PhoneNumber property when it doesnt

Comment: @user2129585 I am not on my windows machine so i can't test the code....This might be a violation but try adding `public virtual PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; }` to `Contact` and see what happens.

Comment: @KomengeMwadila: It compiles if I use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber**s**) but nothing is comming up on the edit/create screens for the phone number

Comment: @KomengeMwadilla: I added it eventhough that will change our model and not be a viable solution we would just be duplicating where the phone number is stored. When I add it it compiles but the create View now has all sorts of fields including the ID which shouldnt be on the create form and when trying to save its erroring out.

Comment: Just add `[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]` to `Ids` in Models. Also did you want a create action or an edit?

Comment: @KomengeMwandilla: I will need both edit and create ... create will default the phone number to primary